# Get data from NodeJs to ReactJs

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I built 2 files. One file is my react app what is oppened at 3000 port, and second is my NodeJs server what is oppened at 4000 port.

```js
//Here is my nodejs file 
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.post('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('POST request to the homepage');
});

app.listen(4000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 4000!');
});

//Here is my react page 
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
const Home = () => {

  useEffect(async function () {
      const url = 'http://localhost:4000/';
      const response =  await fetch(url);
      const data = await response.json();
      console.log(data)
    });

  return(
    <div>
      <h1>Home Page</h1>
      <p>{data}</p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home;
```

How to send `POST request to the homepage` from nodejs file to my reactjs file? I tried with fetch but i dind't find a solution to solve the issue. Who know how to do this?

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: @El Aoutar Hamza, the issue is that i can't send that string to my react page.

Comment: There are a lot of problems with your code: 1) you are sending a GET request instead of a POST request, 2) the variable `data` isn't seen from outside the effect, 3) I doubt that you set CORS on your server..

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the method in the request options for fetch method as follows:

```
const response = await fetch('http://localhost:4000/', {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'cors',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
}).json()
```

Link to docs: [POST request using fetch](https://javascript.info/fetch#post-requests)

Answer (score 1):

In nodejs, try to send an object to client:

```
app.post('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send({ key: 'POST request to the homepage'});
});
```

In reactjs:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
const Home = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({})
  useEffect(function () {
      const url = 'http://localhost:4000/';
      fetch(url, {
         method: 'POST',
         headers: {
             'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
         }
      }).then(rs => {
         // fetch success
         setData(res.data...) // pass an object receive from server into setData function
      });
      console.log(data)
      // At the first time render, console.log here will undefined
      // The second time, you will got the data
  }, []);

  return(
    <div>
      <h1>Home Page</h1>
      // Because data is an object. so you must be render key of data:
      <p>{data && data.key}</p> // key is key of object got from server
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: i got the error `Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

Comment: i got only the text from here `<h1>Home Page</h1>
      // Because data is an object. so you must be render key of data:
      <p>{data && data.key}</p> // key is key of object got from server` but i didn't get ` 'POST request to the homepage'`